# how to delete duplicates from a cell of a column in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates

i have a csv file that look like this:

| venue | innings | bowler |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | p kumarp kumarp kumarz khanz khan |
| a | 2 | AB DindaAB DindaSM PollockSM Pollock,JDP Oram |
| b | 1 | A NehraA NehraA NehraASM Pollock |
| b | 2 | B LeeB LeeB LeeSR WatsonSR Watson |
| c | 1 | SM PollockSM PollockAB DindaAB Dinda |

**Desired Output**

| venue | innings | bowler | no.ofbowler |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | p kumar,z khan | 2 |
| a | 2 | AB Dinda,SM Pollock | 3 |
| b | 1 | A Nehra,SM Pollock,,JDP Oram | 2 |
| b | 2 | B Lee,SR Watson | 2 |
| c | 1 | SM Pollock,AB Dinda | 2 |

and AB Dinda,SM Pollock and SM Pollock,AB Dinda be considered same when we make dummy column

**Code i use**

```
drop_duplicates(subset ="bowler",
                 keep = False, inplace = True)
```

i know my code is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
  venue  innings                                         bowler
0     a        1              p kumarp kumarp kumarz khanz khan
1     a        2  AB DindaAB DindaSM PollockSM Pollock,JDP Oram
2     b        1               A NehraA NehraA NehraASM Pollock
3     b        2              B LeeB LeeB LeeSR WatsonSR Watson
4     c        1           SM PollockSM PollockAB DindaAB Dinda
```

Then you can use regular expression to try to clean your data. For example:

```
import re


def clean(x):
    m = re.findall(r"(.{5,})\1", x)  # 5 is minimal lenght of a name, you can tweak this variable
    for name in m:
        x = x.replace(name, "").strip(",")
    return ",".join(m + [x]).strip(",")


df.bowler = df.bowler.apply(clean)
df["no of bowlers"] = df.bowler.apply(lambda x: len(x.split(",")))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  venue  innings                        bowler  no of bowlers
0     a        1                p kumar,z khan              2
1     a        2  AB Dinda,SM Pollock,JDP Oram              3
2     b        1           A Nehra,ASM Pollock              2
3     b        2               B Lee,SR Watson              2
4     c        1           SM Pollock,AB Dinda              2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need `regex` to extract the duplicates using a custom function to which you apply the column:

```
import re

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

def clean_bowler(text):
    duplicates = [i for i in re.findall(r'(.+?)\1+', text) if len(i)>2] # extract repetitive string patterns and filter out small repetitive string patterns within names (eg recurring letters), you can change the threshold of 2
    other_words = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]', '', i) for i in re.split(r'|'.join(duplicates),text) if i] #filter out the other words using the duplicates as delimiters. Note: there is no way to identify consecutive unique names separately
    return duplicates + other_words

df['bowler'] = df['bowler'].apply(clean_bowler)
df['no.bowler'] = df['bowler'].apply(len)
```

output:

|  | venue | innings | bowler | no.bowler |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | ['p kumar', 'z khan'] | 2 |
| 1 | a | 2 | ['AB Dinda', 'SM Pollock', 'JDP Oram'] | 3 |
| 2 | b | 1 | ['A Nehra', 'ASM Pollock'] | 2 |
| 3 | b | 2 | ['B Lee', 'SR Watson'] | 2 |
| 4 | c | 1 | ['SM Pollock', 'AB Dinda'] | 2 |